# kal calendar integration

Tags: iphone, ios, kal

Downloaded kal.Calendar project from the link https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

I am  Trying to integrate Kal.Calendar in my project.

i downloaded klazuka.kal project on my desktop.

i drag drop the kal.xcodeproj, kal.bundle.

check mark is check libKal.a   under kal.xcodeproj  ...

In Targets I set Direct Dependencies to Kal.

when to project setting

open the header search path... double clicked added the the source Path.

/Users/vmsetty/Desktop/klazuka-Kal-9464bf0-2
This is the path i added in  header search path.

Now i open Other linker Flage added -all_load..

Now i start importing in my application
ApplicationDelegate.m

## import "Kal.h"

I get error Kal.h No such file or directory...

I am worried about this... How to integrate this into my project.

Any one worked on Kal integration . Please help me out.

I thankful to them.

Comment: any one out there... can me help me out with this integration......

Answer (score 1):

Suggest to

- Check the Path of Kal by clicking "Get Info". The following is defined in my project:

  Path: Kal/Kal.xcondeproj

  FullPath: "MyProjectPath"/Kal/Kal.xcodeproj

  Path Type: Relative to Project
- Check the Kal/* is actually located in the directory of FullPath exactly.
- Check the Header Search Paths with value like "Kal" which defined in my project.